# Help with Script for Extracting Specific Data from String

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

Below is a list of data in a single file. I'd like to run this in Powershell.

> LESCAR85      07/31/10      1700678991
>   / 70039536             $35.00
>   SQUADCT8      07/31/10      1698125739
>   / 70039539             $35.00
>   RINGFIEL      07/29/10      11041563 /
>   70039639               $35.00

The 8 digit number and then the dollar amount at the end I would like convert to csv so that I can use that in an excel file. The first set of longer numbers is not always the same which changes the number of spaces between the 8 digit sequence I need and the dollar amount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as ' / ' (slash bounded by spaces) always seperates the data you are interested in from the beginning of the string, then you can use this:

```
get-content yourDataFile.txt | foreach{(-split ($_ -split ' / ')[1] ) -join ','} > yourResult.csv
```

What the foreach loop does:

1. splits each line at the ' / '
2. Takes the second part of the split (what you are interested in), and splits again at whitespace.
3. The resulting elements are then joined together using a comma.